# Most secure way to guard screens with authentication in Flutter and Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a webapp in Flutter that uses Firebase for the backend. The authentication is implemented using Firebase.auth.

I want the user to only access some screens if they are authenticated. For that, I created a solution but I don't know **if it is secure**.

I don't have knowledge in cybersecurity, but I read that it is good to implement a check of the token on the server side. However, I the routes do not admit async functions, so I can't call a server function to do this check.

This is the approach that I have so far for authentication:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  routes: {
    "/": (context) => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
        ? const HomeScreen()
        : const LoginScreen(),
    "/upload": (context) => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
        ? const UploadScreen()
        : const LoginScreen(),
    "/users": (context) => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
        ? const UsersScreen()
        : const LoginScreen(),
  },
);
```

Is this the best way to implement this? Or does it have vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

I am using bloc in my app, in my app in main.dart their is a bloc build that check if state is Authenticated or not,
if user is not authenticated the bloc would redirect user to login.

in order to do so you need to create a function

```
Future<bool> isSignedIn() async => auth.currentUser?.uid != null;
```

then i call this function using bloc. if it returns true then user it authenticated and can use the app.

```
Future<void> appStarted() async {
    try {
      final isSignedIn = await isSignedInUseCase();
      if (isSignedIn == true) {
        final user = await getCurrentUserUseCase();
        emit(AuthenticatedState(user));
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      emit(UnAuthenticatedState());
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      emit(UnAuthenticatedState());
    }
  }
```

another thing to truly add security and only allow authenticated users to use the app and fetch firebase data is using firebase Rules.
u can check `read,write: if request.auth.uid != null;`
this line means user must be authenticated.